# java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods junit springboot2

Tags: spring-boot, junit4, junit5

I am writing Junits for a springboot application. when i run the junit i am getting that there are no methods to run. below is the code
junit:

```java
    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @SuiteClasses({ EmployeeServiceApplication.class })
    public class TestEmployeeService {

        @Mock
        EmployeeRepository empRepo;

        @Autowired
        EmployeeService service;


        @BeforeEach
        void setMockOutput() {
            HashSet<EmployeeView> empSet = new HashSet<>();
            empSet.add(new EmployeeView(1, "firstName", "lastName", "05/30/1986", "EE"));
            when(empRepo.getEmployeeList()).thenReturn(empSet);
        }

        @Test
        public void testGetEmployeeList() {
             Assert.notEmpty(service.getEmployeeList());

    }
```

pom.xml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.employeeService</groupId>
        <artifactId>employeeService</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>employeeService</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

am i missing something ?
i tried lot of options from stackoverflow and they didn't work. and below are the things that i have tried with 
1. @SpringBootTest
2. @mockRunner
3. @SpringBootTest (classes)

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:107)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

page imports:

```
package com.employeeService.employeeService.service;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.HashSet;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import com.employeeService.employeeService.EmployeeServiceApplication;
import com.employeeService.employeeService.service.repository.EmployeeRepository;
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace?

Comment: Make sure that the the test class is in src/test/java folder.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou yes the class is in "src/test/java"

Comment: @aventurin updated the stacktrace

Comment: OK, seems to be JUnit4.

Comment: Test class should be in same package as the source Java class with main method.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou yes both of them are in same package

Comment: I don't see any junit dependency in pom.xml file

Comment: @MariosNikolaou its part of spring boot 2 web dependency

Comment: check this [link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-no-runnable-methods/), i have followed the steps and it's working fine.

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing JUnit4 (RunWith) with JUnit5 (BeforeEach). I guess the test annotation is from JUpiter/JUnit5 that’s why the runner does not find any test methods.

You have to stick with either JUnit4 or Jupiter. Watch your imports!

Comment: i have tried by removing @beforeEach and it did not work

Comment: Show all your imports.

Comment: added imports to the question

Comment: Every import with „jupiter“ in it will not work together with RunWith; use org.junit.Test and org.junit.Before instead. Moreover, for spring testing you probably need a SpringRunner but I’m not an expert on that. Maybe https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing can be a starting point.

Comment: This was my exact issue, re-importing with `import org.junit.Test;` and removing the jupiter import fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Re-importing with import org.junit.Test; and removing the jupiter import fixed the problem